# R: Subset factor levels that co-occur with two levels from another factor

Tags: r, subset, rows

I have a data frame consisting of multiple columns. I want to subset the data frame to only include rows where levels from one factor co-occur with more than one level in another factor. With the simplified data example below, I would be left with just the first two rows, i.e. GeneA, GeneA and TissueA TissueB.

```
A <- c("GeneA","GeneA","GeneB","GeneB","GeneC","GeneC")
B <- c("TissueA","TissueB","TissueA","TissueA","TissueA","TissueA")
df <- data.frame(Gene = A, Tissue = B)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one idea. You define groups with `Gene`. In each group, you want to check if there is more than one unique value.

```
group_by(df, Gene) %>% 
filter(n_distinct(Tissue) >= 2)

   Gene  Tissue 
  <fct> <fct>  
1 GeneA TissueA
2 GeneA TissueB
```

Comment: Thank you - that worked perfectly!

Worth mentioning for others who stumble on this that this requires ddplyr and data.table.

Comment: @C24 I changed `uniqueN()` to `n_distinct()`. You just need the dplyr package.